# Set values of pandas df cell based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df is as follows:

[image]

What I want to do is,
Condition: `Fruit Name` is NOT (`Apple or Mango`) and `veggie Name`== No
Action: Set values in `Veggie Color` and  `Enjoy Eating` = `Unicorn`

My code is

```
df.loc[(~df["Fruit Name"].isin(["Apple","Mango"]))& (df["Veggie Name"]=="Potato"),["Veggie Color","Enjoy Eating"]]="Unicorn"
```

While it does so as follows

[image]

It sets NaN to other cells

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Does the column `Enjoy Eating` exist already? If so, what values populate it before attempting to set "Unicorn"?

Comment: It does exist. It has Yes or No, as shown in the first picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the exact name of the column `Enjoy Eating?`, so it created a new column called `Enjoy Eating` with NaN as default values. Just add the question mark and it will work as expected.

`df.loc[(~df["Fruit Name"].isin(["Apple","Mango"]))& (df["Veggie Name"]=="Potato"),["Veggie Color","Enjoy Eating?"]]="Unicorn"`